# How to obtain a list of files contained in a folder (as a text file)

Tags: automator, folders, file, textedit

I have a huge folder containing musical scores and books (mainly in .pdf).

I would like to create a text document (TextEdit will do just fine) which contains the complete list of the folder's content (possibly even divided into subfolder).

Is it possible? 
If not in a TextEdit file, maybe in Numbers? 
Is there any Automator process that can update that file so that when I add or modify a file, an entry is added / modified?

Answer (score 3):

- Open Terminal
- `find TOP-FOLDER -type f -print | sed 's_/_,_g' > ~/filelist.csv`
- Import `~/filelist.csv` into Numbers or Excel

Comment: Thanks, but ... where is this .csv file saved? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage in your home folder. You can also use `> ~/Desktop/filelist.csv` at the end to save it onto your desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need recently. You used to be able to print Finder windows but you can't do that any more. The best I was able to come up with was using a unix command:

```
ls path/to/folder/in/question > ~/Desktop/folderlist.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @l008com. Where am I supposed to enter the folder's path? Just before I make something bad with the Terminal?

Comment: Yes in the terminal.

Comment: Done! But it just go inside one level. Should I repeat the operation for each subfolder? There are hundreds of them ... Isn't there another method?

Comment: Hundreds of subfolders, you may be out of luck there. You could potentially make a smart folder that would scan down through the subfolders to show all .pdf's for example, but smart folders aren't real folders so you can't view their contents with `ls` as far as I know. You might be out of luck there.

Comment: If you add the parameter R, it will do it recursively and output all items and subfolders. ls <startingPath> -R > filelist.txt

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, I think I might have found something that is not ideal but it definitely provides a temporary solution.

1. In Finder, select the Parent Folder and then Cmd-2 (View as List).
2. Select All and press Cmd-Option-RightArrow to expand the content of all the subfolders.
3. Copy the whole content (Cmd-C)
4. Create a TextEdit document and go to Format > Make Plain Text
5. Paste the content (Cmd-V)

If - as in my case - you had the principal folders with uppercase titles it will be easy to divide the document in categories.
Hope this helps (as it did to me!)